# Display total number of tests/expectations run by Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm converting a large set of QUnit tests to Jasmine. In QUnit, I'm used to seeing the total number of tests across all test modules, displayed at the top. E.g.:

> Tests completed in 157 milliseconds.
>
> 528 tests of 528 passed, 0 failed.

I consider the number of tests to be important information. However, Jasmine's example test runners do not display the total number of tests. Rather, you get something like:

> Passing 106 specs

Each of those specs may contain any number of individual tests. Is it possible to determine the total number of tests that have run, so that I can display it in my test runner? I've looked for information online and in the Jasmine docs but so far haven't been able to find anything.

---

### Solution

Based on @ggozad's reply, I've come up with the following solution, which prints to the console. Suggestions for how to improve it or how to cleanly add the results to Jasmine's HTML output are welcome.

```
var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
var reportRunnerResults = htmlReporter.reportRunnerResults;

htmlReporter.reportRunnerResults = function(runner) {
    reportRunnerResults(runner);

    var specs = runner.specs();
    var specResults;
    var assertionCount = {total: 0, passed: 0, failed: 0};

    for (var i = 0; i < specs.length; ++i) {
        if (this.specFilter(specs[i])) {
            specResults = specs[i].results();
            assertionCount.total += specResults.totalCount;
            assertionCount.passed += specResults.passedCount;
            assertionCount.failed += specResults.failedCount;
        }
    }

    if (console && console.log) {
        console.log('Total: ' + assertionCount.total);
        console.log('Passed: ' + assertionCount.passed);
        console.log('Failed: ' + assertionCount.failed);
    }
};

jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
    return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
};

window.onload = function() {
    jasmineEnv.execute();
};
```

Example console output:

```
Total: 67
Passed: 67
Failed: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *spec* is a *test* in Jasmine. Inside it you can have *expectations* similar to  *assertions* in other testing frameworks. So the number of specs you see reported are the total of each `it` calls:

```
it('passes some expectations', function () {
  ...
});
```

Typically you would group several unit-like tests together in an `it`, which should help you group functionality together and present a more coherent view of how your application is developing.

Now, if you *insist* on wanting to know about the expectations that failed/succeeded in your spec, you can always get this information from your reporter. For instance if you setup up an instance of an `htmlReporter`, you could do:

```
htmlReporter.reportRunnerResults = function (runner) {
...
};
```

Inside your function you can check all sorts of things, here are some hints:

- `runner.specs()` gives you all the specs
- for each of those say `spec`, `results = spec.results()` would give you info about your expectations.
- `results.totalCount`, `results.failedCount`, `results.passedCount` is what you are seeking ;)

Comment: I think I was pretty clear that I'm trying to determine the number of expectations that have run (via `expect`), not the number of specs that have run (`it`).

Comment: @slevithan well there you go ;)

Comment: Thanks for the details added in your edit! I've edited my original question to add my solution based on your answer. I'm new to Jasmine, so any suggestions for improvements are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very useful information.  You might want to append it to the page rather than writing it to the console.  You can replace your console script with...

```
var d1 = document.createElement("span");
$(d1).css('font-size', '10pt');
$(d1).html(' (Total Expectations: ' + assertionCount.total);
$(d1).append(', Total Expectations Passed: ' + assertionCount.passed);
$(d1).append(', Total Expectations Failed: ' + assertionCount.failed);
$(d1).append(')');
$(".passingAlert").append(d1);
$(".resultsMenu").append(d1);
```